# When do I use the comma?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> The monitor being ill, we'd better put the meeting off.
>   The river having risen in the night the crossing was impossible.

In the above two sentences, one uses the comma and one does not. So, when do you use the comma? Are there any rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a matter of style. The only hard and fast rule with commas is that they should be used to separate items in a sentence.

I would put a comma in the second sentence, after 'night'. The thing to remember is that commas make things easier to read. They are a courtesy to the reader.

Read that second sentence as it is, then read it again, but this time, pause for the length of time it takes to say 'comma' in your head after 'night'. Sounds better, doesn't it?

Answer (score 6):

The others are correct that in those examples the comma makes the meaning clearer.

I would add that using the gerund clauses as you have sounds somewhat stilted. Perhaps you could try more straightforward ways to express the same ideas:

> The monitor is ill, so we'd better put off the meeting.
>
> Because the monitor is ill we'd better put off the meeting

and

> The river rose overnight, making the crossing impossible.
>
> The crossing was impossible because the river had risen overnight.

There are obviously other ways to construct the sentences; these are just a couple to give you the idea.

Comment: +1 for balanced advice. P.S. I believe those are participles here, not gerunds.

Comment: @Cerberus: Thanks. But gerunds are verbs that function as nouns, and that's what these look like here.

Comment: Well, you could make the same construction with a past participle: *Given the monitor's illness, we put off the meeting.*

Comment: @Cerberus: Granted, you *could* do that. I was referring to what he *did* do in his examples. But thanks for your kind words.

Comment: Right, sometimes the difference is vague or even arbitrary. I just came by some examples of ambiguity examined by Fowler: http://www.bartleby.com/116/210.html —skip to the example sentences, which are perhaps old, but still good. Do you mind if I make this a Question?

Comment: @Cerberus: Not sure what you mean by "this" in your final sentence, but you are certainly free to ask English.SE any question that comes to mind.

Comment: OK. I meant whether the *-ing* form in absolute constructions is a participle or a gerund, or neither, or both.

Comment: @Cerberus: It sounds like a question worthy of discussion.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly correct to write each of the two sentences with a comma. Here the comma serves as a *bracketing comma* which introduces *the monitor being ill* and *the river having risen in the night* to add to the meaning of the complete sentences

> We'd better put the meeting off

and

> The crossing was impossible.

The bracketing comma may be omitted if the meaning is clear without it, and this happens when what is added by the comma is *short*. In these two examples, it is not wrong to omit the comma, but it seems better to include it.

Answer (score 2):

The rule that applies for your two examples is:

**Use a comma after introductory phrases and clauses.**

A simple sentence:

> I swam across the river.

A simple sentence with an introductory phrase:

> Since it was a sunny day, I swam across the river.

The acception to this rule is: if the introductory clause or phrase is very short, you can leave the comma out--or not, it's your choice.

Both of these are okay:

> On sunday I swam across the river.
>
> On sunday, I swam across the river.

Both your examples require a comma:

> The monitor being ill, we'd better put the meeting off.
>
> The river having risen in the night, the crossing was impossible.