# Comma in "Before I go I will return the book"

Tags: punctuation, commas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do I use the comma?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9434/when-do-i-use-the-comma)

> Before I go I will return the book.

Do we have to use a comma in the above sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would, because the first three words constitute a ‘weak interruption’ to the sentence. This is perhaps clearer with a slight re-ordering of the words to read ‘I will, before I go, return the book.’ The point about a weak interruption is that it can be removed without destroying the sentence. ‘I will return the book’ doesn’t give as much information as the fuller version, but it remains a grammatical sentence.